# Duplex Type A & Type C TR Outlet>>I still want lower half receptacle switched. HOW?

Tags: switch, receptacle

I want to install a new Duplex Type A & Type C TR Outlet. The current old duplex receptacle has the lower one switched. I still want the lower half receptacle switched.  In cases where lamps are preferred to overhead lighting, the switched receptacle is useful when entering a room. . .or controlling a group of lamps.

In my case, I also want USB A & C, and I want it all in one standard single gang box. That way various electronics can be charged more conveniently.  Is there any way to do this? I'm open to home automation but I don't see how I can control only one receptacle on these units which also have USB ports. I don't see why this isn't a product offering without having to resort to some wifi switch integrated into the lamps.

Any suggestions?  Am I missing a product that is available?

Comment: Seems like the new improved gizmos remove the most simple feature you want most.  Unless some company makes them, seems like your choices are to use the USB receptacles with a non switched outlet or use plugged in chargers.

Comment: Given that _most_ new houses have lighting built into the ceiling, there just isn't much call for switched outlets these days. Also, if you have one of these outlets to hand, post a pic of it, there may be a tab you can break... If not, post a link to the one(s) you're interested in, maybe someone will see something you're missing.

Comment: @FreeMan I suspect plenty of houses *still* don't have lighting in the ceiling (except kitchen and bathrooms). But even with switched receptacles, that doesn't necessarily mean *split* receptacles - I know someone who just moved into an apartment and the switched receptacles are *both* receptacles in a duplex, not just one. It isn't that the switched isn't used (though personally I prefer - and have had installed in my own house - ceiling lights) it is that the *split* isn't used so much.

Comment: Old houses have light in ceiling. . .and no such thing as a 1/2 switched receptacle .  I think they should be switched 1/2 in places like 'living' rooms. AND they should have overhead lighting.  AND there should be splittable duplex outlets also having USB A + C, etc. for sale.

Comment: While _you_ may want that @Jim, it seems you're in the minority in the world today and, therefore, manufacturers aren't making the product because they don't believe there's enough demand for it. You might try writing to a couple of companies (or hit their "Contact us" links), to request this product be added to their list. Or... As an alternative, put the charging outlets in one place and the switched outlets elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Given all your requirements, I don't think it's possible. Nobody makes the needed hardware.

If I were in your spot, I would lose the 'single gang' requirement. It might be entirely doable to remove the single box and replace it with an old work double without going in to the wall. Then you could have one always-on USB outlet and one split outlet for your lamp.

Comment: don't want to.  Want 1 gang.  Leviton, et al. need to make this. Geez oh pete!

Answer (score 3):

This is the market at work. Splits are used for MWBCs to double the available power and fit half-switched receptacles. Each of these is a small part of the total receptacle market. People already give that up for GFCI/receptacle combinations, which are very common in kitchens and bathrooms. Even switched receptacles are often not split. USB is a newer option than GFCI, so the precedent of leaving out the split option was already well established. 2nd result, there just isn't that much of a market for split combined with USB. I know I wouldn't want it - I'd hardwire the switched lights.

In the case of GFCI, there is actually a really good reason to not have the split option. A typical GFCI duplex receptacle has 2 hot screws, one for line and one for load, and 2 neutral screws, one for line and one for load. A standard duplex receptacle also has those 4 screws, serving both the use of incoming and outgoing connections (not technically "line" and "load") without having to use pigtails and *also* allowing for split receptacles. To add the split option to a GFCI/receptacle would require fitting an additional pair of wiring locations and lead to confusion about how to handle line vs. load. That does not apply to a non-GFCI USB receptacle, which in fact normally has just one hot and one neutral screw, but it set the baseline of not providing a way to split the receptacles. In the case of USB, if you split the receptacles, how would the typical 2 USB connections be powered? You wouldn't split them - unlike the 120V receptacles where the split is just a bit of metal, splitting the USB ports would double the electronics required. So do they go with the top or the bottom? (If you say top, the next guy will say bottom, or vice versa.)

Plus, adding extra receptacles isn't that hard or that expensive. In my case, I actually have one GFCI location where I want to add (bought the parts, just need to do it already) a second duplex receptacle, chained off LOAD for GFCI protection, with USB A/C. Which will not only provide convenience charging but also provide extra receptacles. Currently landline phone/answering machine + radio, so using a multi-outlet thing just to have room to plug in USB charger - adding a second duplex receptacle with USB A/C will improve things in every respect, including safer/more secure plugging in devices than with a multi-outlet thing without taking extra desk space. Sometimes "all in one" is not actually the best solution.

Comment: Hardwire the switched lights?  These are lamps on floor or end tables, not sconces or ceiling.  I think it's a great option. . .and I want USB right there too all in one neat little package.

Comment: GFCI could be a pain too. . I just put the USB + duplex down line in the kitchen and that works.   I'm still up for option of 1 single gang w/ GFCI+ reset buttons + a couple USB C's.  They could do it if they haven't.

Comment: I've got a grand total of 2 table lamps in use in my house, and both are in rooms with switched ceiling lights as well. I've added (or paid someone to add) ceiling lights to 4 rooms. Personal preference. As far as USB with gfci that would be useful but again gets to how much demand, when you can always chain off the load side of gfci with USB receptacles

Comment: GFCI + USB A & C    seems to exist.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-SmartlockPro-Self-Test-GFCI-Combination-24-Watt-4-8-Amp-Type-A-C-USB-In-Wall-Charger-Duplex-Outlet-White-R02-GUAC1-0BW/319845249

Comment: Interesting. But GFCI & USB A/C together costs quite a bit more than either one by itself, though a bit less than 2 separate added together.

Comment: Yes. I didn't know it was a product either. I think I've thought it could be useful in a bathroom where some small items like chargeable battery powered electric razors may be moving to these usb.  I might also use it in at kitchen or garage.  May have to get one just for novelty sake.

Answer (score 2):

### You Want a Unicorn

...but you can only Have a horse with a horn strapped to its head, on this planet.

- Plug a USB A&C device into the unswitched part of the existing
  receptacle, or a new normal TR receptacle with the hot tab broken and
  the wiring faithfully transferred from the old receptacle. If you
  require an outlet as well, you can get plug-in devices with all 3.
- Replace the current box with a bigger box, or add a new box nearby with an additional receptacle. If you wish to ignore the lessons of how fast things become obsolete, make one of the new things a USB A&C device. In 50 years the NEMA 5-15 will still be useful, unlike the USB A & C that you could have just plugged in and then replaced with the next thing in 5 or 10 or 20 years.

Those are practical options you can actually get and/or do in this world, rather than complaining that they don't fit what you want, which is a Unicorn you won't be finding here.

Comment: Unicorn? Bah humbug!  I don't understand. I have 3 lamps in a living room. Overhead lighting in a living room is terrible. Many prefer lamps. And, in today's world, one wants to charge things like a tablet or phone or laptop while one sits in chair or couch. . . possibly while using these devices.  And forget the adapter clutter.  One neat package in a single gang. . . I am wondering why there is no demand for this. It's got to be possible.  Y'all are making me think I need to persue wireless automation as an option.

Comment: Of course it is *possible*. But guess what - overhead lighting is what a lot of people *want* in a living room (particularly with a dimmer it can work quite well), and using overhead lighting means now instead of 1 receptacle available you have 2 - hmmm, one of those could hold a USB charger and still have another receptacle available for something else.

Comment: Why are you fixated on a single gang? Must be the Scrooge mentality. You can very easily have what you otherwise want by simply putting in an additional single gang, or expanding to a double gang. But sure, waste time carping about your fixation on not having an additional in-wall outlet instead. As for the clutter, once you plug charging cords into your USB-receptacle-thing, you're right back in clutter-land. Tiny Tim would put another outlet in the wall and be happy about it.

Comment: I have three table lamps in my living room as well. They all have local switches. If I wanted to be able to switch them from afar, I'd probably add 'smart switch' outlets or something similar.

Comment: @KMJ -- I think Home Assistant and Shelly Relays are calling for me.  Have to determine if that combo could do it.

Comment: @Jim I run HA and have a few Shelly 1's installed (they're among the very few that are UL listed, last I looked). You'll want a _big_ box in the wall for this! Those Shelly's are BIG! But, yes, with HA, you can _make_ almost anything.

Comment: But, it Has To Be A Unicorn thats fits in a single gang. If Jim was willing to put in another box, or a larger box, then the desired combination of features can be done without any automation, relays, etc...